# Regex - Escape with Negative Lookahead

Tags: php, regex, escaping, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds

I have the following JSON-encoded string:

```
$json = '"|\t|\n|\\\u0027|\\\u0022|"';
```

What is the most efficient way to **escape *all* the (already) escaped chars / codepoints except `\\\u0022` or `\\\u0027`?** I though about using `preg_replace()` with a negative lookahead regular expression but it's not working as I expected, the output should be:

```
$json = '"|\\\t|\\\n|\\\u0027|\\\u0022|"';
```

I'm feeling lost in this ocean of JSON-PHP-PCRE escaping, can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you want? It doesn't quite make sense to me, I would have expected something like `|\\t|\\n...`. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, I'm using `stripslashes()` on it before decoding so the  effect should be exactly the same as yours, removing the escaping from the escaped `\u002[27]` codepoints is my objective. @Marcel, @Unkwntech: Why do you say that? Looks right to me.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I thought it needed at least one key, but of course you can simply assign a string instead of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work with the help of negative lookahead:

```
<?php
  $json = '"|\t|\n|\\\u0027|\\\u0022|"';
  $s = preg_replace('~(\\\\)(?!(\\1|u002[27]))~', '$1$1$1', $json);
  var_dump($json);
  var_dump($s);
?>
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(25) ""|\t|\n|\\u0027|\\u0022|""
string(29) ""|\\\t|\\\n|\\u0027|\\u0022|""
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by exactly what you are trying to do but I can transform your input to your output with this:

```
preg_replace('/\|\\([^\\])\|/', '\\\\\\$1|', $json);
```

Note: I'm not at my computer so I can't verify that this is perfect but it looks good from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?!\\\\)/', '\\\\\\\\\', $subject);
```

This finds a `\` only if it is single (i. e. neither preceded nor followed by another `\`) and replaces it with `\\\`.